Why calling related data with hasManyThrough raised error?
IN laravel 10 app I have 3 related tables :
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title', 255);
    ...

    Schema::create('discounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->tinyIncrements('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name',100)->unique();
    ...

    Schema::create('discount_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('CASCADE');
        $table->unsignedTinyInteger('discount_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('discount_id')->references('id')->on('discounts')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('CASCADE');
    ...

From discount editor I try to load related products with products and got error :
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.discount_id' in 'on clause' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select `products`.*, `discount_product`.`product_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `products` inner join `discount_product` on `discount_product`.`id` = `products`.`discount_id` where `discount_product`.`product_id` = 2 order by `products`.`id` desc limit 6 offset 0) {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.discount_id' in 'on clause' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select `products`.*, `discount_product`.`product_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `products` inner join `discount_product` on `discount_product`.`id` = `products`.`discount_id` where `discount_product`.`product_id` = 2 order by `products`.`id` desc limit 6 offset 0)

In discounts model I have a relation defined :
public function products() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Product::class,
        DiscountProduct::class,
        'product_id', // Foreign key on the products table...
        'discount_id', // Foreign key on the discounts table...
        'id', // Local key on the discounts table...
        'id' // Local key on the products table...
    );
}

Look like the relation above is invalid... Which syntax is valid ?


Based on your table structure, this is better suited as a belongsToMany relationship. It could be possible to achieve this with the hasManyThrough, but belongsToMany is built exactly for this use case

It looks like you're trying to load related products from the discounts model through a pivot table discount_product. The error occurs because the hasManyThrough relationship isn’t suited for many-to-many relationships. In your case, since products and discounts are linked via a pivot table, you should use a belongsToMany relationship instead of hasManyThrough.
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'discount_product', 'discount_id', 'product_id');
}

The parameters for belongsToMany are:

Product::class – The related model.
discount_product – The name of the pivot table.
discount_id – The foreign key on the discount_product table that references the discounts table.
product_id – The foreign key on the discount_product table that references the products table.

